# apply jQuery function to object based on string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following jQuery structure a lot so I want to write it shorter (EDIT:  the addClass and removeClass are EXAMPLE functions, I want to know a general ternary way to apply different functions to an object, so do not tell me about toggleClass which doesn't even work like below code):

```
if(something){
  obj.addClass('class');
}else{
  obj.removeClass('class');
}
```

I want to write it in a single line, so I would like to know how to apply jQuery functions conditionally. Something like the following using a ternary operator, only this doesn't work yet:

```
$[something?'addClass':'removeClass'].apply(obj,'class');
```

This is easily done in regular javascript but how do I structure the above correctly to work in jQuery?

---

EDIT: I am not searching for two separate calls such as:

```
something ? obj.addClass('class') : obj.removeClass('class');
```

Comment: JQuery has toggleClass() to add/remove the classes.

Comment: toggleClass toggles a class without checking a condition, so it's not what I asked for

Comment: So use ternary operator `a > b ? el.addClass() : el.removeClass();`

Comment: I know that way aswell but was wondering if there was a way to pass arguments only once (like in my example) So as you normally could do with regular javascript using apply function, how to do this in jQuery

Comment: Make somethig for yourself and probably for others and write the code which will be clean and easy to understand. $[cond?'addClass':'removeClass'].apply() looks like haystack.

Comment: many programmers get confused by any ternary operator, i myself am used to the .apply structure. I am currently in the situation that I need to make a very big js as short as possible. Apart from that, I am just wondering if my proposed code can work with jQuery. Still didn't receive an answer

Answer (score 1):

Just put it to equal the something, if it is true it will triger otherwise wont triger.

```
    $( this ).toggleClass( "class" ); = something;
```

Comment: that TOGGLES the class if something is true, but that is not what i asked for

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a helper function?

```
function ternary(object, condition, a, b) {
  var method = condition ? $.fn[a] : $.fn[b];
  var args = arguments.slice(4);
  return method.apply(object, parameters, args);
}
```

Then you could do

```
ternary(obj, something, 'addClass', 'removeClass', 'my-class-name');
ternary(obj2, somethingElse, 'slideUp', 'slideDown');
```

Comment: nice suggestion but try it out with jQuery functions (the ones you used) to see that it doesn't work. You can only do this with normal js functions

Comment: @Hacktisch I've updated the code, you need to use `$.fn` instead of `$`